# How to pass additional advertising BLE data?

Tags: objective-c, macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Currently I use the following code on OSX to define advertising data:

```
[peripheral startAdvertising:@{
                               CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: @"hello",
                               // CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey: manufacturerDataKey,
                               CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"00001234-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"]]
                               }];
```

But I should add more [Generic Access Profile (GAP)](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile) data here. I should add here:

- 0x02 «Incomplete List of 16-bit Service Class UUIDs»
- 0x08 «Shortened Local Name»
- 0x16 «Service Data»
- 0x19 «Appearance»

How can I add this data?

Answer (score 2):

Only **CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey** and
**CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey** are supported.

From the [CBPeripheralManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheralManager/startAdvertising:)

> *advertisementData*
>
> An optional dictionary containing the data you want to advertise. The
>   possible keys of an advertisementData dictionary are detailed in
>   CBCentralManagerDelegate Protocol Reference. That said, only two of
>   the keys are supported for peripheral manager objects:
>   **CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey** and
>   **CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey**.

Comment: Thanks. I can not understand such restriction - devices can pass more fields, but with Objective-C usage I can not. Is there any way to override somehow what CBPeripheralManager does and add these data?

Comment: You could file an issue with Apple.